# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ERRORr

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am experiencing this problem when trying to apply a condition to display articles from my database

[image: error]

This is my Article.js component which is where the error indicates

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
 class Articles extends Component {

   state = {
    articles: [],
    status: null
    }
   componentWillMount() {
     this.getArticles();
    }

    getArticles = () => {
    axios.get("https://arthuro-gomez-react.netlify.app/api/articles")
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                articles: res.data.articles,
                status: 'success'
            });
         });
    }

    render() {
    if (this.state.articles.length >= 1) {

        var listArticles = this.state.articles.map((article) => {
            return (
                <article className="article-item" id="article-template">
                    <div className="image-wrap">
                        <img 
   src="https://unhabitatmejor.leroymerlin.es/sites/default/files/styles/header_category/public/2018- 
   10/4%20paisaje%20macedonia.jpg?itok=AELknmF8" alt="Paisaje" />
                    </div>

            <h2>{article.title}</h2>
                    <span className="date">
                        {article.date}
                </span>
                    <a href="#">Leer más</a>

                    <div className="clearfix"></div>
                </article>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div id="articles">
                {listArticles}
            </div>
        );
    } else if (this.state.articles.length === 0 && this.state.status === 'success') {
        return (
            <div id="articles">
                <h2 className="subheader">No hay articulos para mostrar</h2>
                <p>Todavia no hay contenido en esta sección</p>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <div id="articles">
                <h2 className="subheader">Cargando</h2>
                <img 
 src="https://pa1.narvii.com/6707/510b0daee67fbc091f14b9d8ef40aeb6c0d4dc7d_hq.gif"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
}

 export default Articles;
```

Research other OS posts but don't come up with a solution

It should be noted that when I open the page, it does as normal load and then leaves everything blank

I just checked the network console to see and everything marks be directing where it is, if you could see my github repository and see something weird I would appreciate it [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Emocrat3/Curso-React)

And my app web [App web](https://arthuro-gomez-react.netlify.app)

Comment: This would happen if `res.data.articles` is undefined when you get a data result

Comment: can you please check the console to see what data is coming from API?

Comment: I forgot to mention that on localhost, it works perfect, this is in production and presents the error:C

Comment: I'll try a console.log to see what res.data.articles is showing

Comment: I show the empty array, but I don't understand why, if it is in my online database and it is created

Comment: I don't know netlify.app, but `https://arthuro-gomez-react.netlify.app/api/articles` returns a 404 page (HTML-markup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already knew what was happening, something very embarrassing haha, I did not take the routes, because my backend was not in line with netlify, only my frontend, so I proceeded to upload my backend project in heroku and only connected my Global variable for the routes, pointing to the link that indicated heroku :) and ready, solved, thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your API is not working, check this picture from insomia[image: insomiaRequest]
Check  your api. By this your length is empty.

Or try this way

```
Axios.get('http://localhost:yourport/api/someroute')
    .then(res =>{
        const data = res.data;//to save your data response
        console.log("----SETTING DATA-----")
        console.log(data)//to see your data response
        this.setState({articles}) //to set your data response

        console.log("++++++ALL DATA WAS SETTING++++++")
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: I just checked with postman and it doesn't work, it showed me a long error, what could it be? Is it for being in production? In localhost it works perfect for me: s

Comment: Check your firewall, if  you're using a linux server check the configuration of ufw, and allow the port that you're trying access, check this post, I had that problem too.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-un-firewall-con-ufw-en-ubuntu-18-04-es

Comment: Try with this command     sudo ufw allow from your_ip_or_domain   to any port  your_port, for example sudo ufw allow from 203.0.113.4 to any port 8080

Comment: Acabo de intentar con localhost y muestra el articulo con postman http://localhost:3900/api/articles

Comment: Cuando ingresas desde el navegador te manda la página no encontrada. El detalle está en el router de tu app

Comment: I just checked the network console to see and all marks are directing where it is, if you could see my github repository and see something weird I would appreciate it https://github.com/Emocrat3/Curso-React

Comment: OK I'll do it ,wait for me

Comment: You could also see my other question, I think it is better explained, since we know that it is not for the lenght  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62888090/problems-with-my-routes-in-my-production-project-with-node-js?noredirect=1#comment111209609_62888090

Comment: Yes, I can go there but I can't comment yet, because I need 50 of reputation. But I insist, maybe is your server firewall configuration. Do did you check  or not yet?

Comment: You mean CORS??

Answer (score 0):

These are generic errors that occur due to the unhandled error that occurred in your code, it mostly because of mismatching between what expected and what received.

In such cases, you need to try debugging your code to identify what gets failed or different from what expected. This is something considered as drawback of using Javascript as it's not type proof and you encounter such errors a lot.

But browsers help in debugging, so `logs` you pasted above is the `stack trace` of chrome and you can identify where it's failing. It's not guaranteed though as sometimes you probably worked with minified scripts but it's useful a lot.

`Top` log which states error `article.js` click on that it will point you the line of the page where you getting this error, add logs there and you will get an answer.

As just by seeing you probably trying to get `length` of something which is not available.

Try add a log for `res` and see what you received

```
axios.get("https://arthuro-gomez-react.netlify.app/api/articles")
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            this.setState({
                articles: res.data.articles,
                status: 'success'
            });
         });
    }
```

Comment: That showed me   {data: "<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset…s/main.53f72927.chunk.js"></script></body></html>", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}