# Problems with my routes in my production project with node js ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, netlify

I am presenting problems with my project in production, I don't know if I have a bad configuration or something like that, I would like to know if you can see something, I will leave you pieces of my code.

In local it works perfectly, it seems that in production I use netlify, it does not take the routes well

This is the file in my routes folder

```
'use strict'
var express = require('express');
var ArticleController = require('../controllers/article');
var router = express.Router();
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var md_upload = multipart({uploadDir: './upload/articles'});

router.get('/', ArticleController.probar);
router.post('/save', ArticleController.save);
router.get('/articles/:last?', ArticleController.getArticles);
router.get('/article/:id', ArticleController.getArticle);
router.put('/article/:id', ArticleController.update);
router.delete('/article/:id', ArticleController.delete);
router.post('/upload-image/:id?', md_upload , ArticleController.upload);
router.get('/get-image/:image', ArticleController.getImage);
router.get('/search/:search', ArticleController.search);

module.exports = router;
```

So I go to where I export those paths, which is the app.js file

```
'use strict'

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var article_routes = require('./routes/article');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization, X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
next();
});

app.use('/api', article_routes);

module.exports = app;
```

Then I go to my index.js which is where I import the app.js

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3900;
var app = require('./app');

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://emocrat3:emocrat3@reactproyecto.plzbz.mongodb.net/reactProyecto? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => {
            console.log('La conexion a mongodb se realizo correctamente!');

            //Crear servidor y ponerme a escuchar peticiones HTTP
            app.listen(port, () => {
                    console.log('Servidor corriendo en http://localhost:' + port);

            });

    });
```

I will add my repository if you want to see more in depth or I need something to add [Github repository](https://github.com/Emocrat3/Curso-React)

And my website to better observe the error [App web](https://arthuro-gomez-react.netlify.app/)
The error is presented exactly here [ERROR HERE](https://arthuro-gomez-react.netlify.app/blog)

The only path I have made to hit is

```
router.get ('/ articles /: last?', ArticleController.getArticles);
```

And my frontend that I make the query is this

```
    getArticles = () => {
    axios.get("http://arthuro-gomez-react.netlify.app/api/articles")
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                articles: res.data.articles,
                status: 'success'
            });
         });
    }
```

I hope I have formulated my question well, I would appreciate your time to take a look at my problem. Thank you

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined ?? Is this your error ?

Comment: Yes, but it happens because it is not reading the routes, I did a variable monitoring and it marks it empty or undefined, because it is not getting the route of the backend well, since there are indeed articles

Comment: https://arthuro-gomez-react.netlify.app/api/articles  , is this the api?

Comment: router.get ('/ articles /: last?', ArticleController.getArticles);

Comment: I cant understand your concern, as what i can see is, you are getting error because the state is undefined, make sure you are getting the correct response, when you are hitting the API.

Comment: It is not receiving what I want, it is not hitting the api, it seems to me, since in localhost it works perfect

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286927/i-am-getting-error-in-console-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app-r
Try with this ! May be it will help you

Comment: It didn't work for me: c

Comment: can i access the API ? is it public, so i can clone your code and try to resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, I would really appreciate that !!! There is my github repository

Comment: Sorry, I got busy, I will try to solve it as soon as I get time.

Comment: Okay, easy, for my part I will also try to solve it, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

```
router.get ('/ articles /: last?', ArticleController.getArticles);
```

Try removing the spaces

Because in your router you have

```
 router.get('/articles/:last?', ArticleController.getArticles);
```

And that you are doing is

```
 router.get ('/ articles /: last?', ArticleController.getArticles);
```

And try removing, because I understan that you will pass any param there is it?

```
: last?
```

Comment: Hello, the spaces were placed alone when placing it here, but it does not have, I just verified and the last? by having? it is optional, it does not affect you and it works locally

Answer (score 0):

I already knew what was happening, something very embarrassing haha, I did not take the routes, because my backend was not in line with netlify, only my frontend, so I proceeded to upload my backend project in heroku and only connected my Global variable for the routes, pointing to the link that indicated heroku :) and ready, solved, thank you all for your time.

Basically create a global variable in my frontend that will point to the link where my apis were and now it works :)